# What is the difference between a short circuit to an electrical discharge?

Tags: electricity

I understand that there are several possible occurrences of electrical discharge; a very common one is corona discharge which can happen in (almost?) any *utility pole*.

A maybe less common electrical discharge is *short circuit* as when two (loaded enough) battery poles touch one another.

As I might understand wrong I ask: What is the difference between a short circuit to an electrical discharge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between a short circuit to an electrical
>   discharge?

There are two basic categories of electrical arcs. Contact arcing and non contact arcing. A short-circuit is a contact arc. Arcing between conductors separated by air or other insulation is a non-contact arc.

Not contact arcing, or electrical discharge, occurs between conductive parts separated by air or other gas when the voltage is high enough to ionize the gas or break down the insulation causing an electrical arc to occur. A corona discharge will occur when the strength of the electric field (potential gradient) around a conductor is high enough to form a conductive region, but not high enough to cause electrical breakdown or arcing to objects nearby.

Contact arcing can occur when two parts of different potential make actual contact with one another. This routinely occurs at the contacts of mechanical switches during normal operation and is sometimes referred to as operational (non fault) arcing. This is because the surfaces of the contacts are never perfectly flat, so that when contact is initially made or broken, the current density at the high points of the surface vaporizes some material. However, properly designed switches rated for the load can endure many cycles of such arcing without extensive damage.

Short circuits result in a more violent form of contact arcing because of the large amount of available current. These arcs are a potential ignition and fire hazard. The intensity of the arc can vaporize the metal conductors at the site of the short, creating an arc plasma. Short circuit arcs either clear themselves because the contacting materials vaporize, or are terminated by the operation of an over current protective device such as fuse or circuit breaker. More recently devices called AFCI'S (Arc Fault Circuit Interrupters) have been used to more quickly and effectively clear arcing faults.

Hope this helps.